# efficient way to change values in existing golang slice?

Tags: go, slice

I have a slice of a struct like:

```
type Car struct {
    name  string
    price int
    color string
}

cars := make([]Car, 0)
```

The slice gets filled with values and later I want to loop over the the slice and change one specific value (price) again. Currently I do it like:

```
for i := range cars {
        cars[i].price = 10
}
```

I've read that the performance of accessing a slice over it's index isn't great, when dealing with big slices. Would it (performance wise) be better to create a secound slice and copy the values like:

```
newCars := make([]Car, 0)

for _, car := range cars {
    newCar := car
    newCar.price = 10
        
    newCars = append(newCars, newCar)
}
```

Comment: *"Would it (performance wise) be better to create a secound slice and copy the values like"* -- A definitive *NO*.

Comment: *I've read that the performance of accessing a slice over its index isn't great* - can you cite your source?  I'm new to Go, but I would be surprised if that statement was true.

Comment: "I've read that the performance of accessing a slice over it's index isn't great". Stop reading unreliable sources.

Comment: `for i := range cars { cars[i].price = 10 }` is totally fine. If you have performance doubts, always write benchmarks to test it.

Comment: If you're _that much_ into performance (that's not a bad thing in itself), consider getting real about it, and this means not reading random (and maybe severely outdated) posts but actually analyzing what the compiler generates. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/YYfP7Ez6E) is what Go 1.17.x generates for `amd64` out of a slight variation of your example. The actual loop over the slice is on lines 6…17.

Comment: Note that you can see what the compiler generates w/o resorting to 3rd-party services: the `-S` flag can be passed to `go build` via its `-buildflags` argument, and `go tool objdump` provices almost the same result out of the compiled executable image file.

Comment: "accessing a slice over it's index" is about as efficient as you could possibly get, you're directly addressing into contiguous memory. It sounds like you are confusing this with some other optimization method which you don't fully understand.

Answer (score 1):

> I've read that the performance of accessing a slice over it's index isn't great, when dealing with big slices. Would it (performance wise) be better to create a [second] slice and copy the values...

**NO**.

A slice is a [thin] window on top of an underlying array. An array is a contiguous block of member. The cost of accessing an array element by index is trivial. It's just a bit of multiplication and 1 addition under the covers.

To copy the slice to a new empty slice requires at least one memory allocation (and possible more), plus copying memory.